# How to use HDD in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

Newbie Ubuntu user here. I installed my Ubuntu on my SSD (for boot, size: 128G), while I have HDD in my machine (for storage, size: 1T).

When I run my deep learning codes, the codes only run on the SSD, which contributes to no enough space available during its running. Can I run my code on HDD? And it is weird that when I check the 'about the computer', the disk section only shows my SSD 128G without HDD.

This is what my machine gives when I type: `df -hl`

```
Filesystem  Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on  
udev        7.8G     0   7.8G    0%   /dev  
tmpfs       1.6G   22M   1.6G    2%   /run  
/dev/sda1   102G   97G    76M  100%   /  
tmpfs       7.8G   41M   7.8G    1%   /dev/shm  
tmpfs       5.0M  4.0K   5.0M    1%   /run/lock  
tmpfs       7.8G     0   7.8G    0%   /sys/fs/cgroup  
/dev/loop0  315M  315M      0  100%   /snap/pycharm-professional/55  
/dev/loop1   82M   82M      0  100%   /snap/core/4206    
tmpfs       1.6G  136K   1.6G    1%   /run/user/1000
```

It does not show anything about the HDD.

Also, This is my `fdisk`

```
Device    Boot    Start    End     Sectors    Size Id Type  
/dev/sda1   *      2048 216782847 216780800 103.4G 83 Linux  
/dev/sda2     216784894 250068991  33284098  15.9G  5 Extended  
/dev/sda5     216784896 250068991  33284096  15.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.  
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Comment: Is there a formated partition on your HDD?